# Usage of ''doing'' in "You are doing fine"

Tags: do-support, emphasis

> You are **doing** fine.

This sentence is from *The Last Leaf*. What is the case of *doing* in this sentence? Is it an emphatic *do*? I found that *do*, *does* and *did* are more common in "emphatic writing".

Answer (score 2):

**to be doing fine** is not always the same as **to be fine**.

> That's right, one step at a time. Don't look down. You're doing fine. Keep your hands on the ladder.
>
> Keep pedaling and look ahead, not down at your feet. You're doing fine.
>
> You've been with the company for a year now, and you're doing fine. You can expect to be given additional responsibilities soon.

There it means to be carrying out an action in an acceptable or proper manner. It is said in encouragement.

> Hello, Aung Thu. How are you?
>   -- I'm doing fine. And you?

There it means "I am well" or "things are going well for me". It is synonymous with "I'm fine".

Comment: Is it emphatic?

Comment: In the examples I gave, no it is not. When emphatic, **do** will be tensed, not a non-finite form, and will be used  in combination with a verb, as in "You *do understand*, don't you?" or "She *does like* poetry. You said she had no patience for it."

Comment: I know it is an idiomatic expression.

Comment: @Aung Thu: You know what is an idiomatic expression?

Comment: :So sorry for my careless decision. I'm wrong with it.